# BLP using micro data

Tags: industrial-organisation, applied-econometrics

I am currious to know if there has been any work of estimating the BLP model with micro data. Could you give me a reference list.

Comment: What is a BLP model? And the tag reference-request would also improve your question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the same authors Berry, Levinsohn, Pakes have written a second paper that uses both macro and micro data to estimate demand for automobiles as a function of the characteristics of the car.

"Differentiated Products Demand Systems from a Combination of Micro and Macro Data: The New Car Market"

http://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3436404/Pakes_DifferentiatedProducts.pdf